# Email Attachment not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Mail function with attachment file is not working in codeigniter, i m not receiving any mail with attachment.. before i received the mail without attachment but after i used "$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/admin/assets/image/order_complete_file/".$image_name;", i didnt receive any mail..  kindly help me.. Here my coding is

```
$image_name = "some_name";
$content = "some content";
$subject = "Subject Name";          
$this->load->helper('email');
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('abc@gmail.com');
$this->email->to('xxx@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($content);
$attched_file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/admin/assets/image/order_complete_file/".$image_name;
$this->email->attach($attched_file);
$this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use config parameter for `email` library, and set 'mailtype' to 'html'(Default Value is 'text'). If it still fails, you should use the `print_debugger()` function to see why.

```
    $config = Array( 
          'mailtype' => 'html'
        );
$image_name = "some_name";
$content = "some content";
$subject = "Subject Name";   
$this->load->library('email'); 

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('abc@gmail.com');
$this->email->to('xxx@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($content);
$attched_file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/admin/assets/image/order_complete_file/".$image_name;
$this->email->attach($attched_file);
 if($this->email->send()){ echo 'Email send.';}
 else {show_error($this->email->print_debugger()); }
```

Comment: where should i declare $config variable in your  code?

Comment: My bad. You actually have two ways of initializing `$config`. First: `$this->email->initialize($config);`. Second: `$this->load->library('email', $config);`. I'll update my answer right away.

Comment: Thanks for your help i used second way that is $this->load->library('email', $config);.. Now its working fine....

Comment: glad to help. Happy coding.